# how to send the response to browser fromm http.request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js

I am using the sample code from nodejs.org and trying to send the response to the browser .

```
var http = require("http");
var port = 8001;
http.createServer().listen(port);
var options = {
  host: "xxx",
  port: 5984,
  //path: "/_all_dbs",
  path: "xxxxx",
  method: "GET"
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      var buffer = "";
      buffer += chunk;
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(buffer);
      console.log(parsedData);
      console.log("Name of the contact "+parsedData.name);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
```

req.write("hello");
req.end();

But req.write("hello") just does not output the string to the browser ? 
Is this not the right way ? can someone also tell me how to output the response to the html in views folder so that i can populate the response to the static html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 5984,
  path: "/_all_dbs",
  method: "GET"
};

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var rq = http.request(options, function(rs) {
        rs.on('data', function (chunk) {
            res.write(chunk);
        });
        rs.on('end', function () {
            res.end();
        });
    });
    rq.end();
}).listen(8001);
```

Edit:

This node script saves the output to a file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

var options = {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 5984,
  path: "/_all_dbs",
  method: "GET"
};
var buffer="";
var rq = http.request(options, function(rs) {
    rs.on('data', function (chunk) {
        buffer+=chunk;
    });
    rs.on('end', function () {
        fs.writeFile('/path/to/viewsfolder/your.html',buffer,function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('It\'s saved!');            
        });
    });
});
rq.end();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .just another question . Do you know how to display the data (chunk in this case ) in .htm within views folder.

Comment: Added a script which saves the output to a file