# Nodejs: print result on the browser of http.request

Tags: node.js

I am trying to print on the browser the result of an http.request, but I can not it. Usually I can do this with `res.end("text on the browser")` but does not work here.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            res.end(chunk); //I WANT TO PRINT THIS ON BROWSER
    });

});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

I have this error:

```
res.end(chunk);
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'end'
```

How can I do? Please give me a remedy to solve this issue..

Comment: do you really want to write all the HTTP reply by hand? Or are you open to use something like express.js?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway I solved the problem as shown on this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238016/how-to-send-the-response-to-browser-fromm-http-request-in-node-js?rq=1

Comment: then add that as an answer to your question :)